# Insert data in struct** C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct topic
{
    char name[60];
    int QoS;
} topic;

void parseTopics(struct topic **allTopics)
{
    if ((*allTopics = malloc(sizeof(struct topic) * 3)) == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        strcpy((*allTopics[i]).name, "Topic");
        (*allTopics[i]).QoS=0;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    topic *allTopics = NULL;
    int count = 0;
    count = parseTopics(&allTopics);
    printf("Topics:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        printf("Name: '%s' | QoS: %d\n", allTopics[i].name, allTopics[i].QoS);
    }
    free(allTopics);
    return 0;
}
```

How to insert data in **struct? I'm trying like described above, but getting segmentation fault on these lines:

```
    strcpy((*allTopics[i]).name, "Topic");
    (*allTopics[i]).QoS=0;
```

It's important for me to allocate memory in 'parseTopics' function, because in this function I will get amount of topics to parse. Thank you in advice.

Comment: Tip: `(*x).y` is better written as `x->y`

Comment: There's a lot of hard-coded values like `3` in this code. Define these as constants, either via `#define LIST_SIZE 3` or `const int LIST_SIZE = 3`. This way if you change that size, you can change it across the board, not piece-meal.

Comment: `void parseTopics(struct topic **allTopics)` is  a `void` function for which you are attempting to refurn a value: `count = parseTopics(&allTopics);()`

Comment: @ryyker Definitely a sign that `-Wall` is needed here.

Comment: @tadman I will get amount of topics with other functions, this time I need this simple functionality.

Comment: I get that, but stamping `3` all over the place just makes a mess of things. Use a constant at least. `parseTopics` should take that as an argument at the absolute least. Set up for your next step where you need that more dynamic.

Comment: @ryyker yes, I know, already edited it

Comment: Are you sure that `*allTopics[i]` doesn't mean `*(allTopics[i])` instead of `(*allTopics)[i]`?

Comment: After asking _"What's wrong with this code?"_ please do not edit it, except for formatting and to add textual descriptive content in response to a comment.  Once you start editing your code, it becomes a circus.  New people seeing the post for the first time will be misled and confused by the comments and any answers that have been posted.  I have rolled it back to its original form and content.

Comment: @ScottHunter thank you, that was the problem!

Comment: Do yourself and future readers a favor: use a local `struct topic *` pointer for the `malloc` result, and assign it to your "out param" at the end of the function. This avoids a bunch of double dereferencing throughout the function.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, thanks ScottHunter! The problem was that

```
*allTopics[i]
```

was being interpreted as

```
*(allTopics[i])
```

instead of

```
(*allTopics)[i]
```

Fixed code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct topic
{
    char name[60];
    int QoS;
};

const int a = 3;

void parseTopics(struct topic **allTopics)
{
    if ((*allTopics = malloc(sizeof(struct topic) * a)) == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        strcpy((*allTopics)[i].name, "Topic");
        (*allTopics)[i].QoS = 0;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    struct topic *allTopics = NULL;
    parseTopics(&allTopics);
    printf("Topics:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        printf("Name: '%s' | QoS: %d\n", allTopics[i].name, allTopics[i].QoS);
    }
    free(allTopics);
    return 0;
}
```